# Power Query - Date to Julian Date

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I think this is a Julian Date, right?

```
120001 = 01.01.2020
```

I think the structure is like 'CYYDDD'.

How would you convert a Date into such a Julian Date format in Power Query?

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this approach?

```
Text.From([Year]-1900)&Text.PadStart(Text.From(Date.DayOfYear([Date])),3,"0")
```